# List cannot be copied

Tags: python, type-conversion, sniffing, scapy

I am using the sniff() function of Scapy to sniff packet from the ethernet. I store it in a variable called pkt. Later I want to make a copy of the same by appending contents of pkt in another variable buffpkt. Initially I declared both the variables as list but once pkt store the sniff() output it changes its type to instance. Below is the code.

```
pkt=[]
buffpkt=[]
pkt=sniff(prn=lambda x:x.sprintf("{IP : %IP.src%  %IP.dst%\n\n} "),timeout=5,store=1)
buffpkt=pkt
```

I want to make a big list of all the packets sniffed by appending the results to buffpkt but I cannot. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By just assigning one list to another, you just make the first list point to the second list. To copy the list you can use the slicing operator, like this:

```
buffpkt = pkt[:]
```

Now `buffpkt` will be a copy.

Comment: But will this help me to append the new results?

Comment: @sHoM The returned value of `sniff` isn't actually a list, but a custom object that implements list-like access (with the `__getitem__` function). That's the reason the type is `instance`.

Comment: We all love Python for its readability. Let's be obvious, let's be verbatim, let's use `copy` when we're copying stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Use standard library `copy` to copy data structures in Python: http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html